# Verb for "study hard"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

How can the process of studying something intensively be described in one word?

The closest I can think of is *cramming*, but that has connotations of not actually caring about the subject in question, trying to do the least sufficient amount of work. Even though most people indeed tend to study hard in this fashion, it is also possible to be deeply interested in the subject, striving to understand and internalize all the details.

Example:

> The amount of knowledge that had become available to him was astounding, and he spent almost all of his free time [studying hard] in the university library.

Comment: *hard-study*?....

Comment: If he spent almost all his free time *studying*, that context implies that he was studying hard.

Comment: Too late in my time zone to write an answer, but I suggest "delve into".  "She spent hours in the library delving into the latest research on CRISPR."

Comment: @ab2 please do write that answer, I'm probably going to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

A term that common [for learning a new language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_immersion),
but could be used for any field of study, is ***immerse***:

> he *immersed* himself in [or into] his studies

or

> he *immersed* himself in the library books

---

> **[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/immerse)**:
>
>   **("immerse oneself" or "be immersed")**
>   Involve oneself deeply in a particular activity or interest.
>   *‘she immersed herself in her work’
>
>     ‘she was still immersed in her thoughts’*
>
> **[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=immerse)**:
>
>   To engage wholly or deeply;
>     absorb: scholars who immerse themselves in their subjects.
>
> **[Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/immerse)**:
>
> - If you **immerse** yourself in something that you are doing,
>     you become completely involved in it.
>     *Since then I've lived alone and immersed myself in my career.
>
>     He's really becoming immersed in his work.*
>
>   to involve deeply; engross
>     *to immerse oneself in a problem*
>
> **[Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/immerse-yourself-in-something)** – immerse yourself in something:
>
>   to spend most of your time doing something or thinking about it
>   *Sandra immersed herself in work to try and forget her problems at home.*

Comment: I think this is the best answer, actually.

Comment: 'Immerse' is too general, not denoting study.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***research*** to indicate deep study of a topic.

> 1 :careful or diligent search
>   2 :studious inquiry or examination; ...
>   3 :the collecting of information about a particular subject
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/research)</sub>

So in your sentence:

> The amount of knowledge that had become available to him was astounding, and he spent almost all of his free time ***researching*** in the university library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a British word "swot" that means "to study hard" as a verb, but I believe that it is considered slang in Britain and is definitely an uncommon Briticism in the U.S.

"She pored over her text" means she studied her text hard, but it is not one word and requires an object. He "hit the books" has a similar meaning and similar limitation.

"Lucubrate" does not literally mean "to study hard" but may be used metaphorically to mean "to think or study hard."

Comment: How do you use that in a sentence? "My mate was swotting last night?"

Comment: @ Azor-Ahai: I am from the US so the exact nuances of "swot" are not known to me. I have the impression that it conveys the notion of serious and prolonged study, has a derogatory connotation, and is distinguished from "cram." But a native resident of Great Britain would be the best person to ask.

Answer (score 1):

[Lucubrate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lucubrate): *to work, write, or study laboriously, especially at night.*

[Excogitate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/excogitate): *to study intently and carefully in order to grasp or comprehend fully.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***mug up*** means to study intensively.

- The amount of knowledge that had become available to him was astounding, and he spent almost all of his free time **mugging up** in the university library
- Source https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mug%20up

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
**laborious (adjective)

nerd (noun/adjective)**

Answer (score -2):

The word you are looking for is **slog**.

For the sake of completion, I googled it and the meaning is, *work hard over a period of time.* Example: They were slogging to meet the deadline.

In your case,

> ...he spent almost all of his free time **slogging** in the university library.

Comment: At least for me the connotation of slogging is that of slogging through mud.

Comment: I was being facetious. I am quite certain I understand what slogging means.

Comment: @Jim: When someone is 'slogging through the mud' the person is _[plodding (one's way) perseveringly against difficulty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slog)_.

Comment: @Jim: In other words, the person is a going through a *spell of difficult, tiring work*. Doing a difficult and tiring work is not negative. YMMV.

Comment: Agreed. And how does that relate to the person in the OP who is greedily soaking up information at every opportunity?  Does that sound like persevering against difficulty?

Comment: @Jim: Where exactly in the OP is person greedily soaking up information? As far as I can see, the person is *studying something intensively*.

Comment: In the example: *The amount of knowledge that had become available to him was astounding, and he spent almost all of his free time [studying hard] in the university library.*

Comment: @Jim: To the person who is giving all of his effort to gather the information, slogging connects by the meaning: *working hard over a period of time.* (I don't agree with it being a greedy soak of information. It can very well be a *sincere* soaking of information - which is a positive effort in comparison to 'greedy'.)